# Laravel ошибка в создании нового проекта

Tags: php, laravel

В чём суть же проблемы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]я установил laravel,обновил composer и что же я вижу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**In CurlFactory.php line 186:
  cURL error 56: Recv failure: Connection was reset (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
new [--dev] [--force] [--] []**
Подробнее на скриншотах
Что же делать то?

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая же ошибка.

https://github.com/laravel/installer/blob/master/src/NewCommand.php

Line 137:

```
$response = (new Client)->get('http://cabinet.laravel.com/'.$filename);
```

У моего провайдера http://cabinet.laravel.com не открывается. Пришлось воспользоваться буржуйским vpn-ом.